# How set classpath when using exec-maven-plugin to run jruby?

Tags: maven, classpath, jruby

I'm using `exec-maven-plugin` to automatice execution of ruby using jRuby. The problem I'm facing now is that I need to supply the `$CLASSPATH` to jRuby so it knows where some class files are located which is used by the `my_ruby_file.rb`.

If I ran this from the terminal I would have to set the environment variable for $CLASSPATH. If I do that know it would work on my machine locally. I don't have this luxury to set this environment to other machines other than mine now. So I would like maven to take care of that if that's possible?

I've tried to google about and found `<classpathScope>`, and some other suggestion which did not worked for me so I'm asking this question now if someone else have had the same problem like me and solved it somehow?

The configuration I'm using for exec-maven-plugin is as following:

```
<configuration>
    <executable>jruby</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>src/ruby/main/my_ruby_file.rb</argument>
        </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add a `<classpath/>` element :

```
<configuration>
  <executable>jruby</executable>
  <arguments>
    <argument>-J-classpath</argument> <classpath/>
    <argument>src/ruby/main/my_ruby_file.rb</argument>
  </arguments>
</configuration>
```